# fill form via popup

Tags: html, asp-classic, webforms

I have a form and some fields on the form want to be filled via a popup.

My popup basically contains 3 text boxes. After clicking submit on the popup how can i transfer the values of the text boxes to the main form?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- When the popup is submitted & closed, you can reload the asp page & fetch the new results from the server & populate the controls
- The same can be done on the client-side using javascript to fill in the values to the form. You can set the window.opener property when opening the popup to get a reference of the form, get a handle to the form fields you wish to populate & set the values accordingly

HTH.